# Extract messages from stream and ignore data between the messages using a boost::spirit parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to create a (pretty simple) parser using boost::spirit::qi to extract messages from a stream. Each message starts from a short marker and ends with `\r\n`. The message body is ASCII text (letters and numbers) separated by a comma. For example:

```
!START,01,2.3,ABC\r\n
!START,456.2,890\r\n
```

I'm using unit tests to check the parser and everything works well when I pass only correct messages one by one. But when I try to emulate some invalid input, like:

```
!START,01,2.3,ABC\r\n
trash-message
!START,456.2,890\r\n
```

The parser doesn't see the following messages after an unexpected text.

I'm new in boost::spirit and I'd like to know how a parser based on boost::spirit::qi::grammar is supposed to work.

**My question is**:
Should the parser slide in the input stream and try to find a beginning of a message?
Or the caller should check the parsing result and in case of failure move an iterator and then recall the parser again?

Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Should the parser slide in the input stream and try to find a beginning of a message?

Only when you tell it to. It's called `qi::parse`, not `qi::search`. But obviously you can make a grammar ignore things.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b5312750802523a)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Command {
    enum Type { START, QUIT, TRASH } type = TRASH;
    std::vector<std::string> args;
};
using Commands = std::vector<Command>;
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Command, type, args)

template <typename It> struct CmdParser : qi::grammar<It, Commands()> {
    CmdParser() : CmdParser::base_type(commands_) {
        type_.add("!start", Command::START);
        type_.add("!quit", Command::QUIT);

        trash_    = *~qi::char_("\r\n"); // just ignore the entire line
        arg_      = *~qi::char_(",\r\n");
        command_  = qi::no_case[type_] >> *(',' >> arg_);
        commands_ = *((command_ | trash_) >> +qi::eol);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((trash_)(arg_)(command_)(commands_))
    }

  private:
    qi::symbols<char, Command::Type> type_;
    qi::rule<It, Commands()>         commands_;
    qi::rule<It, Command()>          command_;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>      arg_;
    qi::rule<It>                     trash_;
};
int main() {
    std::string_view input = "!START,01,2.3,ABC\r\n"
                             "trash-message\r\n"
                             "!START,456.2,890\r\n";

    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    static CmdParser<It> const parser;
    Commands parsed;
    auto                       f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    if (parse(f, l, parser, parsed)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed:\n";
        for(Command const& cmd : parsed) {
            std::cout << cmd.type;
            for (auto& arg: cmd.args)
                std::cout << ", " << quoted(arg);
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: " << quoted(std::string(f, l)) << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
Parsed:
0, "01", "2.3", "ABC"
2
0, "456.2", "890"
```

Comment: If you don't care about efficiency a lot: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f336aad934f968f8 - when you care about compilation-time: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c064427d30cf8d83

Comment: (note that the latter employs `x3::seek[]` which can be emulated in `qi`  - see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/spirit/repository/example/qi/seek.cpp )

Comment: Hello @sehe, first of all, thank you so much for your prompt reply with a detailed explanation and working example! By the way, it is worth saying, that I wrote my parser based on on your other example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811884/boostspirit-struggle-with-parsing-a-string . So this is not the first time when you help me!

I hope that I understood the underlying idea. To skip unexpected data, it should also be described in terms of grammar and tracked as an alternative input using "|".

Comment: Yes. A more productive way to put it, in my mind, is to just be precise about what _defines_ "trash" or "ignorable content". As soon as you define it, you can accomodate it in your grammar.